# disable default (check all for parent checkbox) kendo-ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have a series/list of checkboxes under two expanded parent checkboxes. I.e. 'Category > Subcategory > all my checkboxes'.

I am simply trying to prevent the default behavior kendo has for these parents which is propping a check all to the checkboxes underneath. I want to write a custom function for when these are clicked but am not sure how to numb out or override kendo-ui's default for these.

I have tried the below but it seems completely ignored by kendo, please not this is a series of checkboxes that are part of another tree - so I cannot just globally redefine how all checkboxes are handled in that tree because I only want to target this list.

```
document.querySelector("#Category").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        chkall(event);
    }, false);

    function chkall(event){ 
        chkst = document.querySelector("#Category-wrapper input[type='checkbox']");
        $(chkst).prop("checked",true).trigger("click");
        console.log("check all fired");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm following your question correctly, to turn off the Kendo Treeview option where checking a parent checkbox checks all the children checkbox, you can simply set the checkChildren setting to false like so:

```
        $("#treeview-kendo").kendoTreeView({
           dataSource: [{
            ---datasource set up---
           }],
           checkboxes: {
            checkChildren: false
           }
        });
```